# Delete file when the file downloaded

Tags: java, struts2

I have to implement a functionality - delete the file on server when user download file is complete. we do not want store that file on server anymore.

I m using struts2 for downloading file on tomcat server. How can i identify file downloading is complete. as of now, i can download file successfully but when the file should be deleted?

code in action class:

```
contentType=new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(fileName);
File f=new File("/home/vikasbarsaiyan/downloadables/"+fileName);
    inputStream = new  FileInputStream(f);
```

### struts.xml

```
<action name="downloadFile" class="mypack.action.FileTransferAction"
            method="downloadFile">
            <result name="success" type="stream">
             <param name="contentType">${contentType}</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                <param name="contentDisposition">filename="${fileName}"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
            </result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried something else. I created a class and extends java.io.FileInputStream. This way:

```
public class NewFileInputStream extends java.io.FileInputStream {

File file = null;

public NewFileInputStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    super(file);
    this.file = file;
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException{
    super.close();
    file.delete();
}
```

and using in action class. Example:

```
inputStream = new NewFileInputStream(file);
```

this was problem solution.

I tested this and success.

Comment: Hi Elon,
Can you provide a demo code here plz. thanks!

Comment: @amit_kumar Great solution. But actually it deletes the file right when the FileInputStream is closed right? It means user could still in the process of downloading a big file from stream after the file's deleted?

Comment: Great solution by @Elon.

Answer (score 1):

try a submit at client end using java script.in OnDownloadComplete() event.
Script at server to receive the submitted file name, find and delete it.

Comment: If anyone close the browser in between downloading file , then javascript code will not run. Am i right?

Comment: This seems to be the only option (if using HTTP), which means you can't be sure if the browser window closed.  I think most browsers support downloading via ftp, since that isn't stateless you can be assured that file was received.